# List all classes in object using reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, mirror

I have an object like:

```
sealed trait Message
object Message {
  case class DoSomething(...) extends Message
  case class DoSomethingElse(...) extends Message
  ...
}
```

what I'm trying to do is to create a list of all Messages in Message object.

What I have so far is:

```
val messages: Iterable[Class[_ <: Message]] = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(Message)
  typeOf[Message.type].decls.collect {
    case c: ClassSymbol if c.toType <:< typeOf[Message] =>
      mirror.reflectClass(c).symbol.getClass.asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: Message]]
  }
}
```

But it yields not very informative error for me:

> scala.ScalaReflectionException: class DoSomething is a static class, use reflectClass on a RuntimeMirror to obtain its ClassMirror

As far as I see, I'm using `reflectClass` on `RuntimeMirror`. Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the `toType` is causing that, and you need to do `c.reflectClass.toType <:< typeOf[Message]` instead?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I forgot to mention that I get the error here `mirror.reflectClass(c)` so I guess it's not the `toType` problem.

Answer (score 9):

After having much more reading about Scala reflections, being richer in knowledge, I found the solution. All I needed was:

```
val messages = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
  typeOf[Message.type].decls.collect {
    case c: ClassSymbol if c.toType <:< typeOf[Message] =>
      mirror.runtimeClass(c).asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: Message]]
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing a reply to yourself and not leaving this question without answer and btw is useful to me too.